# Is RemoveSymbolize the reverse of Symbolize?

Tags: custom-notation

why cann't I use

```
RemoveSymbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["_", "_"]]]
```

to remove all subscripts? 
Just like

```
Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["_", "_"]]]
```

[image]

After RemoveSymbolize[], q1 should be subscript, why isn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RemoveSymbolize` does not seem to respond to patterns. Unclear whether this is by design or a bug. In any case you can use `ClearNotations` to revert from symbol to subscript:

[image]

Comment: Why does Mathematica give this error : ClearAll::wrsym: Symbol Notation`Private`protected is Protected. >> when i run it the second time.

Comment: Because the package begins with `ClearAll["Notation\`Private\`*"]` but there is no `Unprotect["Notation\`Private\`*"]` before that line. After you run the package the first time everything in this context is protected so without the `Unprotect` you get the warning when running a second time. You can either add the `Unprotect` line or just ignore it. None of this alters the answer.